# Angularjs push items with different values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a json in which i have some values that shows in a list using an ng-repeat. When i click in a item of the list i add the item in an empty array that i loop to create some fileds of a form using `push` method. The user can create all fields he wants just click from the first array. The problem is that if i push two or more same items what i write in the input text of the form it repeats in all same input. What i need is that all fields are indipendents even if are the same. I have created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k6s357L8/8/ Thanks for help

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http",
    function($scope, $http){
        $scope.getItems = {
    "data": [
        {
            "label": "first",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd1",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd2",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "bolla"
        },
        {
            "label": "second",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "secondObj",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrname": "asd3",
                            "attrValue": "",
                            "attrType":"text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "key": "2"
        }
    ]

};
    $scope.filterSelected = $scope.getItems.data[0].objects;
        
        $scope.myNewArray = {
            newArray: [
            
            ]
        }
        $scope.pushItems = function pushItems(items) {
            $scope.myNewArray.newArray.push(items);
            console.log($scope.myNewArray);
        }
        
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mycontroller'>

    <div data-ng-repeat="item in myNewArray.newArray track by $index">
        <div ng-if="item.attrType == 'text'">
            <input id="form-f{{$index}}" type="text" placeholder="{{item.attrname}}" data-ng-model="item.attrValue"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="object in getItems.data">
        <div data-ng-repeat="att in object.objects">
            <ul ng-repeat="data in att.attributes">
                <li>
                    <a ng-click="pushItems(data)">{{data.attrname}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _sidenote_: provide your code, not just link to fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `angular.copy` to make a clone of your objects:

```
$scope.pushItems = function pushItems(items) {
    $scope.myNewArray.newArray.push(angular.copy(items));
    console.log($scope.myNewArray);
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/).